# Schedule SQL Job X minutes after SQL Server Agent starts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Job in SQL server which is scheduled to 'Start automatically when SQL Server Agent starts', however, this is creating some issues in our environment. The issue is not SQL specific but because of it we need to delay the execution of this particular job. I cannot schedule this as a recurring job and assign a particular time of a day, it needs to run every time when the SQL Server starts. Is there a way in which I can schedule the job that runs after 15 mins after SQL Server Agent starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just make the first step:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:15:00';
```

(Or, probably better, you could try to resolve whatever "some issues" are.)

However, note that someone can restart the Agent service without restarting SQL Server; or, they could set SQL Server Agent to *not* automatically start at startup, so that the next time the SQL Server service is restarted, your procedure will not run.

If you want to tie some startup activity to *SQL Server* starting, you could probably look into [startup procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-procoption-transact-sql), but if you need it to wait 15 minutes, the first thing in the procedure would be the above `WAITFOR`. Also startup procedures can't have input parameters (or output parameters, but that is less likely to be an issue for a stored procedure you're calling from a job).

Finally, SQL Server 2008 R2? That was barely still in support at the beginning of the *last* decade.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I can explore the Startup Procedure as well ( was not aware of it till now). This is our last month with SQL Server 2008 R2, we are migrating to SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Yay! You will be much happier. STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG alone are worth the upgrade on their own IMHO, but you also get TRY_CONVERT, DATEFROMPARTS, OPENJSON, TRANSLATE, TRIM FROM, CONCAT and CONCAT_WS, so many goodies just in T-SQL, then move to temporal tables and so many optimizer and online operation enhancements, I could talk about this all day… :-)